# What style is required by an <a/> to behave like a <button/> when using `margin: 0 auto` and without a parent with `text-align: center`?

Tags: html, css, button, block, center

**Note: Please don't suggest to add a parent with `text-align: center` because is not useful in this case.**

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kkv687yv/

So let's say I have this html:

```
<a>my link</a>
<button>my button</button>
```

And this css:

```
a {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background: red;
  color: white;
}

button {
  margin: 0 auto;
  display: block;
  background: blue;
  color: white;
}
```

The output is:

[image]

But I would like to have this (dynamic width, not hardcoded or percentage)

[image]

Do you know what else do I need to set on the `<a/>` element to look like that?

Jsfiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kkv687yv/

**Note: Please don't suggest to add a parent with `text-align: center` because is not useful in this case.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

add `display` `table`

```
a {
  background: red;
  color: white;
  margin: 0 auto;
  display:table;
  padding:2px 5px;
}
```

https://jsfiddle.net/kkv687yv/2/

Comment: Thanks! That's perfect.

Answer (score 2):

use this:

```
a {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: block;
    background: red;
    color: white;
    width: 200px; // Change This
}
```

OR:

```
a {
    margin: 0 auto;
    display: table;
    background: red;
    color: white;
}
```

Comment: Oh, sorry I didn't specified that the width sir be dynamic. Thanks